# How to extend the background color to the whole screen in a shell command's output?

Tags: colorscheme, color

I used to have a similar problem with the main screen (IIRC), like here:

[image: vim-lines-bg-problem]

and I solved it by setting `set set t_ut=`, as was suggested in [this question's](https://serverfault.com/questions/268555/how-to-tell-vim-to-extend-the-background-color-to-the-whole-screen) accepted answer. But now I spotted another similar problem:

[image: vim-bg-shell-output-problem]

and I have not been able to fix it, following directions from other similar questions: [Vim Colorscheme Weirdness for Background](https://superuser.com/questions/678905/vim-colorscheme-weirdness-for-background-not-non-text-area/678995), [256 color support for vim background in tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/399296/256-color-support-for-vim-background-in-tmux), namely setting the TERM variable's value to `screen` or `screen-256color`. I tried, but to no avail:

```
foo@bar$ TERM=screen
foo@bar$ echo $TERM
screen
foo@bar$ vim /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

I use Terminator as a terminal, but, it seems, this doesn't matter, since in the default Ubuntu terminal the problem is the same.

It's not that this is a huge problem, but it's still annoying.

Could anyone help? Thank you in advance.